# Como resolver aspas de value de elmento html com javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho um script que cria botões com eventos onclick, mas estou com problemas ao atribuir seu valor.

Veja o script:

```
for (var i = 0; i < cursos.length; i++) {    
$("#cursos").append("<button class='ui-btn ui-corner-all optCurso' data-transition ='slide' onclick="
                                                    + "'controller.setNomeCurso('" + cursos[i].Value + "')' >"
                                                    + cursos[i].Name + "</button>")
}
```

Ao criar o botão ele fica da seguinte forma:

```
<button class="ui-btn ui-corner-all optCurso" data-transition="slide" onclick="controller.setNomeCurso(" anáse="" de="" sistemas')'="">Anáse de Sistemas</button>
```

Como eu poderia resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar aspas simples na chamada do parâmetro da função.

Segue o exemplo funcionado:

```
var cursos = [{Name: "Teorema de D'Alembert", Value:"Teste '123 "},{Name: "Teste2", Value: 345}];
var createButton = function(){

$("#cursos").append("<button class='ui-btn ui-corner-all optCurso' data-transition ='slide' onclick=\"controller.setNomeCurso('"+ cursos[0].Value.replace(/'/g, "\\'") + "')\">"+ cursos[0].Name + "</button>");
}

$("#createButton").click(function(){
    createButton();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alysonsm/qkyjuud9/2/

No exemplo acima, também é previsto o tratamento para quando ocorrer a utilização de aspas simples dentro do valor que será impresso no parâmetro da função.

Para tratar o erro das aspas simples dentro do valor, basta tratar a string substituído os valores das aspas simples por: \':

```
    var texto = "Exemplo '123'";
    var exemplo = texto.replace(/'/g, "\\'"); //Exemplo \'123123\';
```

Comment: O acontece se eu tiver um curso sobre o Teorema de D'Alembert?

Comment: Marquei como resolvido, mas desmarquei por causa do comentário do @ctgPi e agora jovem? rsrsrs...

Comment: O que ele falou é verdade. Acredito que a melhor abordagem é não usar concatenamento de strings e sim utilizar os recursos da linguagem para criar os elementos. Utilizar o javascript puro vai garantir o funcionamento em navegadores antigos. Fique a vontade! ;)

Comment: Quanto ao Teorema de D'Alembert você deve fazer o tratamento das aspas simples e duplas.

 str = str.replace(/'/g, "\\'");

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195568/how-do-i-add-slashes-to-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: Obrigado @alysonsm você teria como postar essa observação na resposta por favor meu amigo?

Comment: Dá uma olhada no exemplo atualizado da resposta.

Comment: Tu é bichão mesmo hem! Muito obrigado meu amigo. Funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: Pensando um pouco mais aqui, isso não é suficiente pra resolver o problema. e.g. `var cursos = [{Name: "Teorema de D'Alembert", Value:"\" onmouseover=\"alert(&#39;pwned!&#39;);\" data-bla=\""}, …]`. Também precisa rolar um `.replace(/"/g, "&quot;")`.

Answer (score 1):

Nesses casos é melhor criar o elemento em uma outra linha e usar os métodos do jQuery pra colocar os valores dinâmicos nos devidos lugares:

```
var button = $("<button class='ui-btn ui-corner-all optCurso' data-transition ='slide'></button>");
button.click(function () { controller.setNomeCurso(cursos[i].Value); });
button.text(cursos[i].Name);
$("#cursos").append(button);
```

(dependendo exatamente de onde vem `i`, talvez você precise de algo tipo `button.click((function (nomeCurso) { return function () { controller.setNomeCurso(nomeCurso); }})(cursos[i].value));` pra capturar direito a closure)

Você também vai precisar colocar um `type="button"` se esse botão for aparecer dentro de um formulário.

---

Você realmente precisa fazer isso com jQuery?

```
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.type = 'button';
button.className = 'ui-btn ui-corner-all optCurso';
button.setAttribute('data-transition', 'slide');
button.addEventListener('click', function () { controller.setNomeCurso(cursos[i].Value); }, false);
button.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cursos[i].Name));
document.getElementById('cursos').appendChild(button);
```

Isso funciona em qualquer IE 8+; se você aceitar ser compatível só com IE 11 e Edge, você pode trocar `button.setAttribute('data-transition', 'slide')` por `button.dataset.transition = 'slide'`.

O jQuery [encoraja esse estilo de código](http://www.doxdesk.com/updates/2009.html#u20091116-jquery), concatenando strings; esse problema que você encontrou é o primo mais novo do SQL Injection. Concatenar strings pra gerar tags HTML é pedir pra criar buracos XSS no seu aplicativo.

Comment: Olá meu amigo, muito obrigado pela ajuda. O meu `i` vem de um laço `for` que existe. Tentei a primeira opção, mas infelizmente não funcionou. O erro gerado foi: `Uncaught ReferenceError: cursor is not defined` isso justamente na linha em que você acrescenta o evento click. A segunda opção também não deu certo, retornou o seguinte erro: `ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Value' of undefined`.

Comment: Mea culpa, eu tinha um typo de cursos pra cursor (corrigido)

Comment: Eu havia percebido e corrigi na hora de testar em meu código, os problemas infelizmente persistem, não existe maneira de corrigir o código postado pelo @alysonsm ?